# How to bind an Angular 2 expression and TypeScript method?

Tags: typescript, angular

What I am trying to do is to show the full name, when first name and last name are entered.

This works:

```
<h1 [hidden]="!firstName || !lastName">Hello {{lastName + ', ' + firstName}}!</h1>
```

This does not work (what is the correct way of invoking a method defined in the class?):

```
<!--h1 [hidden]="!firstName || !lastName">Hello {{fullName()}}!</h1!-->
```

This does not work either:

```
<button ng-click="alertFullName()">show full name</button>
```

Here are the files:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'src': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
    </script>

    <!-- 3. Bootstrap -->
    <script>
      System.import('angular2/platform/browser').then(function(ng){
        System.import('src/hello_world').then(function(src) {
          ng.bootstrap(src.HelloWorld);
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 4. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <hello-world>Loading...</hello-world>
  </body>

</html>
```

src/hello_world.html:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name here">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name here">
<hr>
<h1 [hidden]="!firstName || !lastName">Hello {{lastName + ', ' + firstName}}!</h1>
<!--h1 [hidden]="!firstName || !lastName">Hello {{fullName()}}!</h1!-->
<button ng-click="alertFullName()">show full name</button>
```

src/hello_world.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  // Declare the tag name in index.html to where the component attaches
  selector: 'hello-world',

  // Location of the template for this component
  templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html'
})
export class HelloWorld {
  firstName: string = '';
  lastName: string = '';
  function fullName(): string {
    return firstName + ', ' + lastName;
  }
  function alertFullName() {
    alert(firstName + ', ' + lastName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @Günter Zöchbauer wrote (i.e., use `(click)`, not `ng-click`), this code

```
function fullName(): string {
   return firstName + ', ' + lastName;
}
function alertFullName() {
  alert(firstName + ', ' + lastName);
}
```

should be

```
fullName():string {
    return this.firstName + ', ' + this.lastName;
}
alertFullName() {
   alert(this.firstName + ', ' + this.lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If we take a look at the documentation for [Angular 2 templates](https://github.com/alexeagle/angular2-distro/blob/master/docs/core/01_templates.md#expressions) we can see that interpolation in the form of `{{bindMe}}` can bind only to properties:

> Expressions can be used to bind to properties only. Expressions represent how data should be projected to the View. Expressions should not have any side effect and should be idempotent.

This means the following example is 'illegal' as it represents a function invocation:

```
<h1 [hidden]="!firstName || !lastName">Hello {{fullName()}}!</h1>
```

You could instead have a getter `fullName` which produces the value you want:

```
export class HelloWorld {
  firstName: string = '';
  lastName: string = '';
  get fullName () {
      return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }
}
```

And then consume `fullName` in your template:

```
<h1 [hidden]="!fullName.length">Hello {{fullName}}!</h1>
```

Comment: From the [Template Syntax guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation), Interpolation section: "The expression can invoke methods of the host component as we do here with `getVal()`".  So I don't think it is illegal to call a method on the component.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<button ng-click="alertFullName()">show full name</button>
```

should be

```
<button (click)="alertFullName()">show full name</button>
```

This works fine for me

```
<h1 [hidden]="!firstName || !lastName">Hello {{fullName()}}!</h1>
```

(I had to change the `"!firstName || !lastName"` expression because I use Dart and there the `null` check has to be explicit)